# proximity search on different rows

Tags: pandas, elasticsearch

For data that indexed from dataframe like this:

```
import json

mycolumns = ['name']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=mycolumns)
rows = [["John Abraham"],["Lincoln Smith"]]
for row in rows:
    df.loc[len(df)] = row
print(df)


jsons = json.loads(df.to_json(orient='records'))
n = 0
for j in jsons:
    j['injection_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime('now')
    es.index(index="prox", doc_type='record', body=j)
    if n%1000==0:
        print (n/1000),
    n+=1
```

I am trying to search match_phrase that is spread on two rows as described here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_multivalue_fields_2.html#_multivalue_fields_2

es.search(index="prox", body={"query": {"match_phrase":{"name": "Abraham Lincoln"}}})
I expected to get 1 hit because of the ways how arrays are indexed but I don't get any hit.

Comment: Are you sure that the documents were indexed correctly? Could you please check from ES side?

Comment: how do I check it from es?

Comment: Use [match_all](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-all-query.html) query. You can do it from python too, like this: `es.search(index="prox", body={"query": {"match_all":{}}})`

Comment: {'_shards': {'failed': 0, 'skipped': 0, 'successful': 5, 'total': 5},
 'hits': {'hits': [{'_id': 'AWB4fJdLKzgOuzu-tnmY',
    '_index': 'prox',
    '_score': 1.0,
    '_source': {'injection_timestamp': '2017-12-21T09:51:57',
     'name': 'John Abraham'},
    '_type': 'record'},
   {'_id': 'AWB4fJhUKzgOuzu-tnmZ',
    '_index': 'prox',
    '_score': 1.0,
    '_source': {'injection_timestamp': '2017-12-21T09:51:59',
     'name': 'Lincoln Smith'},
    '_type': 'record'}],
  'max_score': 1.0,
  'total': 2},
 'timed_out': False,
 'took': 1}